# Not able to clear cookie what ever I do using PHP

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie, httpcookie

I have tried a few ways to clear my cookies on *localhost*. Whatever I do, I am unable to delete them in Chrome and Firefox in normal mode, but it is working fine in Chrome's Incognito and Firefox's Private Browsing modes.

Here is my code:

```
$name = 'keepsignin';

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])){
   $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
   foreach ($cookies as $cookie_id => $cookie_value){
       if($cookie_id === $name){
          self::set_cookie($cookie_id, $value, $expiry, $path, $domain);
       }
   }
}
```

After clearing the cookie manually things work fine, but I am not able to delete cookies that already exist.

Comment: `explode` returns a numeric array, not an associative array, so `$cookie_id` will be a number, not the name of the cookie.

Comment: is there a way to get the exploded return as an associative array with names.?

Comment: thanks for the fast reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']` is a semi-colon delimited list of key-value pairs in the form:

```
key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3;...
```

You split the string at the <kbd>;</kbd>, but not the <kbd>=</kbd>

I think you might be looking for something like:

```
$name = 'keepsignin';

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
   $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
   foreach ($cookies as $cookie) {
       list($cookie_id, $cookie_value) = explode('=', $cookie);
       if($cookie_id === $name){
          self::set_cookie($cookie_id, $value, $expiry, $path, $domain);
       }
   }
}
```

Note the use of [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to assign `$cookie_id` and `$cookie_value` in one operation.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend iterating the `$_COOKIE` superglobal rather than parsing `$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']` yourself.